# CopyOnWriteArrayList internal state is transient

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist

CopyOnWriteArrayList is marked Serializable. But it's  internal state is transient. Can anyone please answer what are we trying to serialize in this type of List.

```
/** The array, accessed only via getArray/setArray. */
private volatile transient Object[] array;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`writeObject`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject%28java.io.ObjectOutputStream%29) method has been overridden to store the state in specific manner. So the actual store, i.e. `array` being transient is not affecting the serialization of a CopyOnWRiteArrayList object.

The transient members in an object will be left during the default serialization process by the JVM. But, if you override `writeObject()`, then that method definition will be used for serializing the object instead of the default serialization strategy.

Comment: I want to know why CopyOnWRiteArrayList  need to customize serialization?